# Selecting Dynamic date range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which bring the data based on their Activity date. The query goes like:

```
where al.ACTIVITY_DATE between '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2018-12-01 00:00:00.000'
```

It select all the activity falls under this data range.

Now as its 2019 i need to make changes on my date range as `2019-12-01 00:00:00:.000`.

What i don't want to do is to make changes every year on that report manually. Is it possible to select data of last 2 years along with the data of this year till 31st dec 2019?

Comment: Is the beginning date always 2017-01-01? In 2020, are you getting three years of data? Or literally, "last 2 years".

Comment: Unclear.  What does this mean?  "Is it possible to select data of last 2 years along with the data of this year till 31st dec 2019?"   What happens on Dec 31st?   Exactly what is "data of last 2 years"?   Calendar years?   Years ago today?

Comment: I always want 2 year data on that report, as the year moves on the report should only show 2 year data however as my report has future joiner i would like to keep current year data to select till Dec 31st.

Comment: Is `ACTIVITY_DATE` actually a `date` column? Or is it `datetime`, `datetime2`, etc.? [Please don't use BETWEEN for date range queries](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
WHERE al.ACTIVITY_DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(yy,-1,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0))
                           AND DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)
```

This will make it the last two years dynamically.

This is the start of the previous year

```
DATEADD(yy,-1,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

This is the end of the current year.

```
DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest way to derive the beginning of last year:

```
DECLARE @start date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,1,1);

-- 2018-01-01
```

And then this is the simplest way to do a full date range queries for last year and this year, without worrying about the data types, rounding, etc. ([read this to see why `BETWEEN` is a bad idea](http://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx)).

```
...
WHERE al.ACTIVITY_DATE >= @start 
  AND al.ACTIVITY_DATE <  DATEADD(YEAR, 2, @start); -- 2020-01-01
```